# Undefined offset: 0

Tags: wpdb, php

Here is my PHP function:

```
function getUserIDandPush($ul){
    global $table_prefix; // Prefix for Database table
    global $user_login;
    global $wpdb; // Wordpress WPDB database method 
    $dt = $table_prefix; //Tables Prefix
    $as = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$dt.'users WHERE user_login = "'.$ul.'" ');
    $usID = $as[0]->ID;
    wp_set_current_user($usID, $ul);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($usID);
    do_action('wp_login', $ul);
}
```

The issue is that `$as[0]->ID` returns ***Undefined offset: 0***,

I'm not sure why is this returning that.  The function works and does exactly what I want. But, why this error occurs?

Seeking some learning..

Comment: `$ul` is not defined, and you should really read about securing database requests. :)

Comment: Its an intranet site. Not to worried as its only accessible from our computers. But I see your point.

Comment: This is all being done via ldap

Comment: If you are getting this data from the wordpress users table, you should take a look at `get_user_by`, one of the options is get by login https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

```
function getUserIDandPush($ul){
    global $table_prefix; // Prefix for Database table
    global $user_login;
    global $wpdb; // Wordpress WPDB database method 
    $dt = $table_prefix; //Tables Prefix
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && isset($_SERVER['LOGON_USER'])) {
        $as = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$dt.'users WHERE user_login = "'.$ul.'" ');
        $usID = $as[0]->ID;
        wp_set_current_user($usID, $ul);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($usID);
        do_action('wp_login', $ul);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat. You could also have (and for paranoia's sake might want to as well) check the length of the $as array is >= 1 before trying to access element 0 - I think that's a more general solution for problems like this.

Comment: tried that prior to this attempt but it returned a Non-Object error, but great suggestion.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: I noticed that on the site, when I printed it would give me an Array with everything including the object... then it gave me a array() which was empty... That led me to believe the issue is in relation to the fact its running multiple times.